# What happen to the lasso mask keybind ctrl shift lmb drag in 4.0

Tags: sculpt-mode

What happen to the lasso mask keybind ctrl shift lmb drag in 4.0 i can't use it anymore they changed a lot of stuff it seem even default keybind for brush as been changed

Comment: Blender have released a [Video](https://youtu.be/QhYplmY1gtU) about keymap updates in version 4.0 which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of John Eason i got my answer.

They changed from <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> to <kbd>Right Mouse Buttom</kbd>.

So you can lasso mask with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>